# jQuery load select option not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a `dropdown` list that store language (fr,es,en...).
I've a **flag** `image` that takes source based on the select option.
on change event work well but not at first load

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" >
  <asp:ListItem Text="Ita" Value="it-IT" /> 
  <asp:ListItem Text="Eng" Value="en-us" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Esp" Value="es-AR" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

`JavaScript`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ddlLanguages").on('load change', function () {

    var select = $("#ddlLanguages").find(":selected").text();
    var pathItalia = "../....jpg";
    var pathInghilterra = "../....jpg";
    var pathSpagna = "../.....jpg";

    switch (select) {
      case "Ita":
        $("#flagImg").attr("src", pathItalia); 
        break;
      case "Eng":
        $("#flagImg").attr("src", pathInghilterra);
        break;
      case "Esp":
        $("#flagImg").attr("src", pathSpagna);
        break;           
    }
  });       
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd imagine that your `$("#ddlLanguages")` selector isn't finding the list, being that you're targeting the `ID` of an ASP Control rather than its `ClientId`. Try putting `ClientIdMode="static"` on the `<Asp:DropDownList>`, or doing `$("#<%=ddlLanguages.ClientId%>").find(...)` instead.

Comment: nothing change in both cases

Comment: can you please go to the browser and copy the html out of that code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dropdown doesn't really load anything, so is has no `onload` event to fire.

If you want to run the function on first pageload, fire the change event manually

```
$("#ddlLanguages").on('change', function () {
    // your code here
}).trigger('change'); // fire on load
```

Comment: it would solve the problem of the load, but not when it changes

Comment: @robert - In the question it states *"...on change event work well"*, so I'm guessing that part works ?

Comment: i missed that part

Comment: I solved like suggested $("#ddlLanguages").on('change', function () {
    // your code here
}).trigger('change');